# Pyspark: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when Saving the dataframe to parquet/csv

Tags: java, pyspark, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have been using pyspark 2.3 on jupyter notebook on Lenovo Pc (windows 10 & Ram 48 G), I tried to save  dataframe as parquet or csv  format but i got this error :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o394.csv.
...
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 17, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
...
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
...
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
...

----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50525)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\****\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\****\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\****\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "F:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\accumulators.py", line 235, in handle
    num_updates = read_int(self.rfile)
  File "F:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\serializers.py", line 683, in read_int
    length = stream.read(4)
  File "C:\Users\****\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

By following one of the recommendations from other questions have been posted here, I created the sparkSession  as follows :

```
SparkSession \
  .builder \
  .master("local[*]")\
  .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
  .config("spark.memory.fraction", 0.8) \
  .config("spark.executor.memory", "16g") \
  .config("spark.driver.memory", "16g")\
  .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" , "800") \
  .config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled",'true')\
  .config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","16g")\
  .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: OutOfMemoryError is one of the most frequent errors you can get in pyspark, but may come from different sources. It appears on write because `.write` is action and everything before is a bunch of lazy transformations and don't do any actual processing. The stacktrace is too general and says nothing. Maybe you should share full stacktrace and with some code if possible. If not, check if your pipeline runs at all with `df.sample(0.01)`. Check how the size of result files change depending on a sampling percentage. Try saving intermediate data. Pay attention to shuffles like `join` and `groupby`.

Comment: There are other resulting dataframes saved using the same code but its size is smaller.

Comment: So your code is working, but not with that particular data? This can happen if, for example, you do `groupBy` on a column where one value is dominating (like 0 or null), then a lot of data could go to one executor and result in OOM error. Just guessing. To check if it happens on executor or driver run `.count()` instead of `.write.csv()`. If it fails on `.count()`, you probably have a big partition on some executor.

Comment: The count method is working but it consumed a lot of time  and the count resulting is 1325460 row

Comment: Have you got a solution for it? I have been in this situation today. I can execute a `count()` in a `.parquet` file, it gives me 2 millions rows count. But when I try to read this parquet file and `df.toPandas()` I get the `Java heap space` error.

Comment: @RonanFelipe Just ran into the same issue with `df.toPandas()`. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I remember me and my team found a solution, but I don't remember details, I don't have access to that code base anymore. A few things I still remember that we studied to solve it, like: lazy evaluation, memory management, clean up the data checking for some columns that could cause problems. Sorry for not remembering the details here XD. @ArthurPassos